# Scraping a single value from an HTML table and inserting into an Excel cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, screen-scraping, forex

Please see the code below.  I am compiling a list of unusual currency pairings in excel and I wish to scrape this data with VBA.  I only want to insert the value itself into the cell.  Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?  I am getting a 'Run-time error '91': object variable or With block variable not set'.  I'm relatively new to VBA and i've put a lot a deal of thought into this.

```
Sub ie_open()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TxtRng As Range
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
    ie.NAVIGATE "http://www.barchart.com/quotes/forex/British_Pound/Costa_Rican_Colon/%5EGBPCRC"
    ie.Visible = True

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test Sheet")
    Set TxtRng = ws.Range("A1")
    TxtRng.Value = ie.document.getelementsbyname("divQuotePage").Item.innertext

End Sub
```

This is the data which I am trying to scrape:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what line causes the error message?  Or should we try to guess?  Guessing:  You don't have a Sheet19.  That would cause that message.

Comment: Thanks, I quickly amended that.  It now shows a 'Run-time error '91': object variable or With block variable not set'.  I believe the issue is with the reference to the html element.

Comment: When the error occurs, if you choose the Debug option, a particular line should be highlighted in your code.  That would be the line that is causing the error.  You need to show that clearly in your question

Comment: change `ie.document.getelementsbyname("divQuotePage").Item.innertext` to `ie.document.getelementsbyname("divQuotePage").Item(0).innertext`

Comment: you may also try: `ie.document.getElementById("dtaLast").innertHtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that accomplished at web scraping, but that kind of error often means that what you are looking for isn't there.  In particular, I don't see `divQuotePage` in the screen shot you provided.

But if you want the quote (793.19) you could do something like:

```
Dim V As Variant
Set V = ie.document.getelementbyid("dtaLast")
TxtRng = V.innertext
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.barchart.com/quotes/forex/British_Pound/Costa_Rican_Colon/%5EGBPCRC" ' should work for any URL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        x = .document.body.innertext
        y = InStr(1, x, "Last Price")
        Z = Mid(x, y, 19)

        Range("A1").Value = Trim(Z)

        .Quit
    End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can target that element with a CSS selector of `div.pricechangerow > span.last-change`;
which can be simplified to `.last-change`.

The "." means class and you can retrieve this specific item with

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector.querySelector(".last-change").innerText
```

That is for the website's current incarnation at 2018-06-30